# Running java based webdriver scripts in unix server

Tags: unix, webdriver

I have written webdriver+TestNG scripts in windows using java. Now there is an upcoming requirement to run the same scripts in UNIX server without much of code modification. I have heard about running tests in headless browser, but I dont know about this much. I searched a lot but there is no clear and simple response to start looking into this.

Is it possible to just change the driver instance to htmlunitdriver and run the same in unix environment? How could I create the tests as a package and move to unix environment for running the scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your existing script by making few changes in driver instance creation. Suppose you are using Firefox driver for your test, then you can run your script in headless mode using virtual display Xvfb (Xvfb is an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware and no physical input devices).

Below are the steps to run your tests in headless mode:

1. Install Xvfb
2. Start the Xvfb by executing this command `Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`  [Xvfb Manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?Xvfb%201)
3. Then create a Firefox driver instance that uses virtual display started in step 2 as below:

   `FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary();
    fb.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":99");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb,null);`

Now your script will run in headless mode. You may need to change few other things like path of your test data or any other references that uses windows file system (like C:\)

Comment: Thanks Surya for your response. I will start with these information and reply back if this is the approach that I was expecting